# Python: how to sum up values within linked lists

Tags: python, linked-list

Given a list, return the sum of all the values in the list.

If the input list is empty, return 0.

```
# class ListNode(object):
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.next = None
#
def solution(head):
    current_node = head
    while current_node:
        print(current_node.value)
        current_node = current_node.next
```

above is what i have so far which gives me the ability to traverse/iterate through the list but to sum it up is a whole different beast, i can't conquer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a variable for the accumulation.

```py
def solution(head):
    current_node = head
    accumulation = 0
    while current_node:
        accumulation += current_node.value
        current_node = current_node.next
    return accumulation
```